# how to use ggplot, geom_line and geom_ribbon to draw multiple y axis in a layout

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-ribbon

There are different data sets as bottom.

1-1.Data Set(cidf_min.csv)

| name | number | value | samples | conf | lower | upper | level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 1 | 0.056008 | 100 | 0.95 | 0.05458 | 0.059141 | 2 |
| apple | 2 | 0.048256 | 100 | 0.95 | 0.046363 | 0.059142 | 2 |
| apple | 3 | 0.042819 | 100 | 0.95 | 0.040164 | 0.059143 | 2 |
| apple | 4 | 0.038663 | 100 | 0.95 | 0.035155 | 0.059144 | 2 |
| apple | 5 | 0.035325 | 100 | 0.95 | 0.030146 | 0.059145 | 2 |

1-2.Data Set(newdf_min.csv)

| name | number | value | samples | conf | lower | upper | level | max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 2 | 0.01854 | 100 | 0.95 | -0.06963 | 0.045235 | 2 | 2 |

```
  '''code'''
  cidf<-read.csv("D:/cidf_min.csv")
  newdf<-read.csv("D:/newdf_min.csv")
  p_min<-ggplot(cidf, aes(x=number, y=value, group=name))+geom_line(aes(color=level))+geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lower, ymax=upper, fill=level, group=name), alpha=0.3)+geom_text(data=newdf, aes(label=name, color=level), hjust=-0.2, vjust=0.5, size=3, show.legend=F)+coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,max(cidf$number)*1.2))+xlab(~"Con (\u00D7"~C[max]*")")+ylab(~"score ("*mu*"C/"*mu*"F)")+theme_bw()
```

2-1.Data Set(cidf_max.csv)

| name | number | value | samples | conf | lower | upper | level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 1 | 0.068832 | 100 | 0.95 | 0.061945 | 0.069416 | 2 |
| apple | 2 | 0.065256 | 100 | 0.95 | 0.053687 | 0.065841 | 2 |
| apple | 3 | 0.060492 | 100 | 0.95 | 0.046201 | 0.06155 | 2 |
| apple | 4 | 0.05585 | 100 | 0.95 | 0.039848 | 0.058739 | 2 |
| apple | 5 | 0.047585 | 100 | 0.95 | 0.033555 | 0.056066 | 2 |

2-2.Data Set(newdf_max.csv)

| name | number | value | samples | conf | lower | upper | level | max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 2 | 0.024221 | 100 | 0.95 | -0.04546 | 0.076362 | 2 | 2 |

```
  '''code'''
  cidf<-read.csv("D:/cidf_max.csv")
  newdf<-read.csv("D:/newdf_max.csv")
  p_max<-ggplot(cidf, aes(x=number, y=value, group=name))+geom_line(aes(color=level))+geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lower, ymax=upper, fill=level, group=name), alpha=0.3)+geom_text(data=newdf, aes(label=name, color=level), hjust=-0.2, vjust=0.5, size=3, show.legend=F)+coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,max(cidf$number)*1.2))+xlab(~"Con (\u00D7"~C[max]*")")+ylab(~"score ("*mu*"C/"*mu*"F)")+theme_bw()
```

3-1.Data Set(cidf_mean.csv)

| name | number | value | samples | conf | lower | upper | level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 1 | 0.069673 | 100 | 0.95 | 0.069673 | 0.069673 | 2 |
| apple | 2 | 0.06133 | 100 | 0.95 | 0.057955 | 0.062792 | 2 |
| apple | 3 | 0.060497 | 100 | 0.95 | 0.046201 | 0.06155 | 2 |
| apple | 4 | 0.054623 | 100 | 0.95 | 0.044241 | 0.058739 | 2 |
| apple | 5 | 0.039852 | 100 | 0.95 | 0.031906 | 0.043719 | 2 |

3-2.Data Set(newdf_mean.csv)

| name | number | value | samples | conf | lower | upper | level | max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 2 | 0.014323 | 100 | 0.95 | -0.06793 | 0.045717 | 2 | 2 |

```
  '''code'''
  cidf<-read.csv("D:/cidf_mean.csv")
  newdf<-read.csv("D:/newdf_mean.csv")
  p_mean<-ggplot(cidf, aes(x=number, y=value, group=name))+geom_line(aes(color=level))+geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lower, ymax=upper, fill=level, group=name), alpha=0.3)+geom_text(data=newdf, aes(label=name, color=level), hjust=-0.2, vjust=0.5, size=3, show.legend=F)+coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,max(cidf$number)*1.2))+xlab(~"Con (\u00D7"~C[max]*")")+ylab(~"score ("*mu*"C/"*mu*"F)")+theme_bw()
```

I already drew  3 plots using code of `ggplot`, `geom_line` and `geom_ribbon` etc.

1. I want to merge plots of `p_min`, `p_max` and `p_mean`.
2. `p_min`, `p_max` and `p_mean` must locate in y axis.
3. x axis is number(1,2,3,4,5).

Let me know how to draw plots of multiple y axis using complex variables in a layout.

Comment: please provide a reproducible example, it is very hard to help you if we cant reproduce you code ( and so far there is no easy way to extract your data tables) see here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @yuliaUU  connected you to show the picture of result example as link. You can click the blue character above.

Comment: The problem is that to help you I have to run your code so I can write you a solution. Which I can't do since "D:/cidf_min.csv" does not exists on my computer.

Comment: @yuliaUU I already uploaded the data set in "##1-1, 1-2, 2-1, 2-2, 3-1, 3-2" above.  Can I provide you my original data file?

Comment: Yes, you showed what your datasets looks like, but they are not reproducible as I can't just copy paste it into r . Instead, to make it easier for others to reproduce your resulys run dput(cidf) and copy paste the output here. Do it for each dataset you use. Or another way is you can upload your data on some website like github and share a link to them (if you are allowed to share them)

Comment: got them! thanks for the link!

Comment: @yuliaUU My original file include different parameter unlike the parameter of this site.

Comment: @yuliaUU It is perfect result. thank you very much. Can I delete result image that you made.

Comment: Did you mean that you want me to remove the picture from my answer?

Comment: Also, if you are satisfied with my answer, can you mark it as an answer?  You just need click on the checkmark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.

Comment: @yuliaUU Yes. Please, allow me to remove your result picture.ㅠㅠ

Comment: I removed it as you requested:)

Comment: @ already voted regarding your answer.^^

Comment: @yuliaUU Thank you for agreeing my suggest and helping my problem.

Comment: No worries at all:) thanks for the fast responses!

Answer (score 0):

What I did I first renamed each dataset to cidf1,cidf2, and cidf3 so that they won't mix.
and the same for newdf. I added a column `type` that basically has info of what type of graph it is. I was not sure whether you know the tidyvesre, so I used basic R to add a column using $ operator

```
#Set 1
cidf1 <- read.csv("cidf_min.csv")
cidf1$type ="P_min"
newdf1<-read.csv("newdf_min.csv")
newdf1$type ="P_min"
 
#Set 2
cidf2<-read.csv("cidf_max.csv")
cidf2$type ="P_max"
newdf2<-read.csv("newdf_max.csv")
newdf2$type ="P_max"

#Set 3
cidf3<-read.csv("cidf_mean.csv")
cidf3$type ="P_mean"
newdf3<-read.csv("newdf_mean.csv")
newdf3$type ="P_mean"
```

then I combined them together:

```
cidf = rbind(cidf1,cidf2,cidf3)
newdf =rbind(newdf1,newdf2,newdf3)
```

And plotted them, setting `color=type` to color each line according to the dataset. I removed other things that you had in your ggplot as they were not related to your question asked.

```
ggplot(cidf, aes(x=X, y=value))+geom_line(aes(color=type)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lower, ymax=upper, fill=type), alpha=0.3) +
  xlab(~"Con (\u00D7"~C[max]*")")+ylab(~"score ("*mu*"C/"*mu*"F)")+theme_bw()
```

So it is very close to what you are looking for. Let me know if I misinterpret what you want to do and I will update my code